# cacti - multi cpu util - multi line OID

Tags: cpu, oid, cacti, mib

I have the OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2
I got 24 rows (I have 24 core server),
I want to create one graph with all the rows to see the utilization.

Please help me :)

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and I created a data input methode in Perl which uses Net::SNMP.

Get the script here: 
https://gist.github.com/1139477

Get the data template here:
https://gist.github.com/1237260

Put the script into $CACTI_HOME/scripts, make sure it's executable and import the template.
Make sure you got Perl's Net::SNMP installed.

Have fun!
Alex.